# SharePoint 2010 Approval Workflow for a sub site?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-workflow

I m new to SharePOint Workflows. I could see that the following workflows are currently ACTIVE. I went ahead and created a sub-site. In that sub-site, I want to attach an Approval (OOTB) to my document library. But I don't see any OOTB workflows in my sub site.

```
http://myServer/mySubSite/_layouts/wrksetng.aspx
```

it says There are no workflows currently associated with this site. I clicked on Add a new workflow. It showed me this link

```
http://myServer/mySubSite/_layouts/AddWrkfl.aspx
```

however, there are only 2 workflows- Schedule Web Analytics Alerts and  Schedule Web Analytics Reports.

I want to be able to add OOTB SharePOint Approval workflow to my sub site. How do I do that? I want to see 'Workflows' link under my sub site when I click on my sub site's sitesettings-->Site Administration-->Workflows. 
TIA.

These are all the workflows in my site collection under this link

```
http://myServer/_layouts/wrkmng.aspx
```

1. Approval
2. Collect Feedback
3. Collect Signatures
4. Disposition Approval
5. Schedule Web Analytics Alerts
6. Schedule Web Analytics Reports
7. Three-state Translation Management
8. Collect Signatures - SharePoint 2010
9. Collect Feedback - SharePoint
10. 2010   Publishing Approval
11. Approval - SharePoint 2010

Any thoguhts? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably go into sharepoint designer, click on the workflows tab on the left hand side and in the section labled "Globally re-usable workflows" click on the approval workflow to create a copy of it and then try to add the copy.  Also you may be trying to add an approval workflow to an invalid content type.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to understand your exact issue, but it sounds like you are looking to add an OOTB Approval workflow to your document library.

You said you are looking at the Sub-Site's 'Site Settings' but have you looked in the list settings for that document library? An OOTB approval workflow would be added at the library not the site level.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Unless you are telling me what I suggested was wrong, I do believe I did provide an answer to the question. It may be poorly formatted but looking at the document library level is the logical next step. Not sure what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I went through same issue , and google it ,
the fix I found was that the sharepoint had the feature deactivated for each site I created and I had to activated it {site Action -> site collection features }
hope it works for you